# How can I call a postgres function in myBatis xml mapper?

Tags: postgresql, function, mybatis

how can I call a function in myBatis using xml?

I have this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_audit_deletions(IN days numeric, IN 
table_name text) 
RETURNS void AS
$body$
DECLARE
   interval INT;
BEGIN

    UPDATE table_name SET backup = 1 WHERE backup = 0 AND creationdate >= now()::DATE - days AND creationdate < now()::DATE;

    IF copy_func(table_name, days) > 0 THEN
    DELETE FROM table_name WHERE backup = 1;
    ELSE
    UPDATE table_name SET backup = 0 WHERE backup = 1;
    END IF;
END
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can i call this function passing parameters? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML statement and Java mapper method would look as follows.

```xml
<update id="saveAuditDeletions" statementType="CALLABLE">
  {call save_audit_deletions(#{days}, #{text})}
</update>
```

```java
void saveAuditDeletions(@Param("days") Integer days, @Param("text") String text);
```

FYI, it can be done without XML.

```java
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
@Update("{call save_audit_deletions(#{days}, #{text})}")
void saveAuditDeletions(@Param("days") Integer days, @Param("text") String text);
```